# CSV File Splitting with specific size

Tags: c#, file, csv, header, tableheader

Hi guys I've a function which will `create multiple CSV files` from a `DataTable` in `smaller chunks based on size` passed through `app.config` key/value pair.

Issues with the code below:

1. I've hardcoded the file size to 1 kb, when I'll pass a value of `20`, it should created csv file of `20kb`. Currently it's creating a file size of `5kb` for the same value.
2. For the last left records it's not creating any file.

Kindly help me to fix this. Thanks!

code :

```
public static void CreateCSVFile(DataTable dt, string CSVFileName)
    {

        int size = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"]);
        size *= 1024; //1 KB size
        string CSVPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CSVPath"];

        StringBuilder FirstLine = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder records = new StringBuilder();

        int num = 0;
        int length = 0;

        IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(column => column.ColumnName);
        FirstLine.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));
        records.AppendLine(FirstLine.ToString());

        length += records.ToString().Length;

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            //Putting field values in double quotes
            IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field =>
                string.Concat("\"", field.ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\""), "\""));

            records.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
            length += records.ToString().Length;

            if (length > size)
            {
                //Create a new file
                num++;
                File.WriteAllText(CSVPath + CSVFileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + num.ToString("_000") + ".csv", records.ToString());
                records.Clear();
                length = 0;
                records.AppendLine(FirstLine.ToString());
            }

        }            
    }
```

Comment: I'll rather like to directly write `CSV Files` in smaller chunks of specified file size directly from `DataTable`. I'm not able to write all the records. The `If` condition is only looking for `length > size` so it's leaving the last left records and not creating any file for those records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), `Linq` means [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb669162.aspx) will be performed.

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(FilePath))
{
   // logic here.
}
```

From MSDN

> The **ReadLines** and **ReadAllLines** methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you ***must***
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, ***when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient***.

Now so, you could rewrite your method as below.

```
    public static void SplitCSV(string FilePath, string FileName)
    {
        //Read Specified file size
        int size = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileSize"]);

        size *= 1024 * 1024;  //1 MB size

        int total = 0;
        int num = 0;
        string FirstLine = null;   // header to new file                  
        var writer = new StreamWriter(GetFileName(FileName, num));

        // Loop through all source lines
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(FilePath))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstLine)) FirstLine = line;
            // Length of current line
            int length = line.Length;

            // See if adding this line would exceed the size threshold
            if (total + length >= size)
            {
                // Create a new file
                num++;
                total = 0;
                writer.Dispose();
                writer = new StreamWriter(GetFileName(FileName, num));
                writer.WriteLine(FirstLine);
                length += FirstLine.Length;
            }

            // Write the line to the current file                
            writer.WriteLine(line);

            // Add length of line in bytes to running size
            total += length;

            // Add size of newlines
            total += Environment.NewLine.Length;
        }
   }
```

Comment: As you can see in the Question I've posted, I'm also including headers in each file creation - `string FirstLine = arr[0];` and `writer.WriteLine(FirstLine);` How to implement this in **`foreach loop`**?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple... you don't need to put all your lines in memory (as you do in `string[] arr = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);`).

Instead, create an `StreamReader` on the input file, and read line by line to line buffer. When the buffer is over your "threshold size", write it to disk into a single csv file. The code should be something like this:

```
using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
{
    var linesBuffer = new List<string>();
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        linesBuffer.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        if (linesBuffer.Count > yourThreshold)
        {
            // TODO: implement function WriteLinesToPartialCsv
            WriteLinesToPartialCsv(linesBuffer);
            // Clear the buffer:
            linesBuffer.Clear();
            // Try forcing c# to clear the memory:
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, reading the stream line by line (instead of the whole CSV inpunt file, as your code did) you have better control over the memory.